# QXmlSchemaValidator получение ссылки в XSD

Tags: qt, xml, xsd

Можно ли получить ссылку на элемент схемы при валидации XML с помощью QXmlSchemaValidator?
например при валидации обнаружена ошибка в атрибуте "myCode". Я хочу получить ссылку на элемент схемы, описывающий этот аттрибут:

```
<xs:attribute name="myCode" use="required">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Код. 1 символ</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

В документации нашел только как получить текстовое описание ошибки.

PS: Если в QT это нереально, возможно есть такая возможность с помощью libxml?